# Microsoft ODBC Excel Driver Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, excel

I am using **XL Report Builder** version 2.1.4 and trying to execute the following script but, keep getting the error "Microsoft ODBC Excel Driver Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression".

```
select Bidders.*
From Bidders
where
If :Param1 = 1 Then
    Due > 0 and
    Left(Event,2) <> 12
Else
    Due = 0 and
    Left(Event,2) <> 12
End If
order by
      Name
```

`Param1` is a user-entry parameter that can be either "0" or "1".
 Does anyone have any advice as to what operator I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `if` in the query looks suspicious.  Try writing the query as:

```
select Bidders.*
From Bidders
where (:Param1 = 1 and Due > 0 and Left(Event,2) <> 12) or
      (:Param1 <> 1 and Due = 0 and Left(Event,2) <> 12)
order by Name;
```

You can simplify this as:

```
select Bidders.*
From Bidders
where Event not like '12%' and
      ((:Param1 = 1 and Due > 0) or
       (:Param1 <> 1 and Due = 0)
      )
order by Name;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Your 1st suggestion works just fine, but the 2nd generates an error.